# How I can number of the same elements in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm making Shopping Cart, and I need to show all elements which were added to Shopping Cart, but elements which are the same should appear in the list only 1 time , but in this case i need to show quantity of these elements...

```
 {shoppingCart.map((book) => (
                    <div key={book.id} className="book-element">
                        <div className="col-1">
                            <img src={book.image}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-4 shp-description">
                            <p>{book.title}</p>
                            <p>Cover: {book.hardCover === false ? 'Paperback' : 'Hardcover'}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">{}</div> // here i need to set quantity of the same elements
                        <div className="col-2">{book.price}$</div>
                        <div className="col-1">
                            <i className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
```

Comment: sounds like you need to process the array to remove the dupes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: Or you use reduce to get the counts

Comment: @epascarello ok, it's clear how to delete the same elements.. But how also i can show quantity of the same elements?

Comment: map's job is to transform data.  the source observable pipes the data to the map where the lambda function transforms the data and emits the output.  https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/reading-the-rxjs-6-sources-map-and-pipe-94d51fec71c2

Answer (score 1):

as @epascarello says, you need to process your list before mapping it to react components

```
processBookList(shoppingCart).map((book) => ...)
```

and then you have something like this

```
function processBookList(bookList) {
   // iterate over your list of books and build a new array
   // or maybe use array.reduce if it suits you
   return proccessedBookList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So process the books, basic task of combining records

```
getCartData() {
  // loop over the cart
  const combined = this.shoppingCart.reduce((obj, book) => {
    // reference the book we already have or create a new record
    obj[book.id] = obj[book.id] || {  ...book, qty: 0 };
    // increase the qty
    obj[book.id].qty++;
    return obj;
  });
  // return the array of books with qty
  return Object.values(combined);
}
```

Comment: In this case I have object in object...also I don't understand why we use 'return Object.values(combined);' in this case.. it returns values of object and not array with object...

Comment: For example, I added 5 items (3 of them are the same, it meanse qty === 3), but when i use your example it shows that every item has qty 3/4/5/6 etc.. so....